# Why does Go create threads when executing a command?

Tags: go

Analyzing this standard code from the documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#example-Cmd.Run)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "1")
    log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")
    err := cmd.Run()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

I noticed that when the external command is executed, additional threads (1494, 1495, 1496, 1497) are created? What are they for, is it possible to somehow avoid them?

```
$ ./s
$ pstree -ap 

  |   |-bash,19563
  |   |   `-s,1493
  |   |      |-sleep,1498 60
  |   |      |-{s},1494
  |   |      |-{s},1495
  |   |      |-{s},1496
  |   |      `-{s},1497
```

Comment: The Go runtime spawns thread whenever it needs to, and is not within your control. What is the problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: I have some users on my servers that have a limited maximum number of possible processes (RLIMIT_NPROC) and they use my go program that launches an external program depending on the user's settings. Since, when accounting for resources, the Linux kernel equates a thread with a process, then the user does not have so many resources left to start something else.

Comment: Unfortunately if they are using Go, any blocked thread will spawn another to ensure GOMAXPROCS is always maintained. This should probably be handled by adjusting resource limits on the server, but they could also set GOMAXPROCS to a lower value than the default to provide some extra threads.

Comment: With GOMAXPROCS=1 the number of threads is reduced from 4 to 2, but unfortunately this is still a lot for me. Apparently it is necessary to rewrite the program in another language. Thanks for the comments anyway.